# CNN to first make feature key-points prediction then classify image on the base of these keypoints using Pytorch or TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch

I have already trained an Image Classifier using MobileNet in Pytorch to classify between close eyes image and open eyes image and also deployed it to mobile using Tensorflow

[image]    [image]

But problem is that the [dataset](http://parnec.nuaa.edu.cn/xtan/data/ClosedEyeDatabases.html) is not big enough and it also doesn't work when the face object is far away or zoomed out.
I want to classify face with predefined key points like following

[image]

I want to make a CNN to first make feature key-points prediction and then classify image on the base of these keypoints.

Please guide me to any research paper or guide to predict feature keypoints using CNN and classify keypoints to two classes using Deep Learning techniques. The more Deep Learning used is better

I have already read about unsupervised machine learning but it is not working for me. I want to used deeplearning and pytorch or tensorflow

Comment: "The more Deep Learning used is better" may I ask you why?

Comment: I trained the mobileNet model in Pytorch and using tensorflow i deployed it on mobile.
i want to use deep learning better because i have already deployed CNN using tensorflow on mobile.  


if i use unsupervised machine learning i.e SIFT then i'll have to work hard to deploy it again on mobile 
just help me to make feature prediction using Deep Learning's convolutional neural network and then classify image using those features by using any technique

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me you have enough data. The key is preprocessing. I'll suggest to use [MTCNN](https://kpzhang93.github.io/MTCNN_face_detection_alignment/) (implementations: [one](https://github.com/ksachdeva/opencv-mtcnn), [two](https://github.com/timesler/facenet-pytorch), [three](https://github.com/davidsandberg/facenet/tree/master/src/align)) for lightweight face and eyes detection, crop eyes and pass them through your net. Of course you should learn on cropped eyes (not whole images). You can get more precise eyes keypoints by libs like [OpenPose](https://github.com/CMU-Perceptual-Computing-Lab/openpose), [FAN](https://github.com/1adrianb/face-alignment) or [Seeta](https://github.com/seetafaceengine/SeetaFace2).